# How to assign headers to a dataframe based on the content within each column

Tags: python

As you can see in my code below i'm assuming the csv file will always contain 7 columns, and i only name the columns i need. The problem is this may be an incorrect assumption. Is there anyway to create headers for the two columns i need but based on the data within those columns. For example one column i need will initially always have rows that contain Curncy, for another column it would always have . followed by a number such as .41 Then of course drop the other columns as i'm already doing. Please see sample data at the bottom.

At the end of the day i want to end up with two columns in my dataframe['IsoCode', 'ConversionRate']. **Clarification**: primary goal is to assign headers dynamically without assuming that the source csv will have any specific number of columns but assuming it will always have columns that contain the specific data i want as seen below.

Also please feel free to offer any on how my code is styled, after casually glancing over the PEP 8 style guide i'm still not sure if i'm following best practices for python styling. The fact that all my code that's calling my functions is at the bottom weirds me out, would it be good practice to put them in a def main() and then just have main() at the bottom?

```
        from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Define the columns to be added to the dataframe VERY RELEVENT FOR MY QUESTION
    cols = ['IsoCode', '9', '8', 'ConversionRate', '6', '5']
    
    # Salesforce query to retrieve active currency types
    currencyTypeQuery = 'SELECT Id, IsoCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsActive = true'
    
    # Path to the CSV file
    CSV_FILE_PATH = r'\somefilepath\fxrates.csv'
    
    # Final columns to be used for dataframe from the CSV
    FINAL_COLUMNS = ['IsoCode', 'ConversionRate']
    
    
    def getCurrencies():
        """
        Retrieves currency data from the CSV file.
        Returns a Pandas DataFrame with the extracted data.
ALSO VERY RELEVENT
        """
        with open(CSV_FILE_PATH) as fp:
            for row in fp:
                if row.startswith('START-OF-DATA'):
                    break
            df = pd.read_csv(fp, header=None, names=cols)
            deleteRows = df.index.get_loc(df[df.IsoCode == 'END-OF-DATA'].iloc[0].name)
            cleanedRowDF = df.iloc[:deleteRows]
            return cleanedRowDF
    
    
    def removeColumns(df):
        """
        Removes unnecessary columns from the provided DataFrame.
        Returns the DataFrame with the final columns.
        """
        df.drop(columns=df.columns.difference(FINAL_COLUMNS), inplace=True)
        return df
    
    
    def cleanIsoCodeColumn(df):
        """
        Cleans the IsoCode column in the provided DataFrame by removing unwanted characters and filtering for 3-letter codes.
        Returns the cleaned DataFrame.
        """
        df['IsoCode'] = df['IsoCode'].str.replace('  Curncy', '')
        df = df.loc[df['IsoCode'].str.len() == 3]
        return df
    
    def salesforceConnection():
        """
        Establishes a connection to Salesforce using the provided credentials.
        Returns a Salesforce instance.
        """
        return Salesforce(instance_url='someurl',
                          username='someUsername',
                          password='pw',
                          security_token='someToken')
    
    
    def querySalesforce(sf, query):
        """
        Executes a Salesforce query to retrieve currency type data.
        Returns a Pandas DataFrame with the queried data.
        """
        result = sf.bulk.CurrencyType.query(query)
        usedCurrencies = pd.DataFrame(result)
        usedCurrencies.drop(['attributes'], axis=1, inplace=True)
        return usedCurrencies
    
    
    def uploadToSalesforce(sf, dataToSalesforce):
        """
        Uploads data to Salesforce using the Salesforce instance and the provided data.
        """
        update_results = pd.DataFrame(sf.bulk.CurrencyType.update(dataToSalesforce, batch_size=100, use_serial=True))
        print(update_results)
    
    # Retrieve currencies from the CSV file
    df = getCurrencies()
    
    # Remove unnecessary columns
    df_removedColumns = removeColumns(df)
    
    # Clean the IsoCode column in the DataFrame
    df_cleanedIsoCodeColumn = cleanIsoCodeColumn(df_removedColumns)
    
    # Connect to Salesforce
    sf = salesforceConnection()
    
    # Query existing currency data from Salesforce
    usedCurrencies = querySalesforce(sf, currencyTypeQuery)
    
    # Set the IsoCode column as the index in the queried DataFrame
    usedCurrencies.set_index('IsoCode', inplace=True)
    
    # Update the queried DataFrame with the cleaned DataFrame based on IsoCode index
    usedCurrencies.update(df_cleanedIsoCodeColumn.set_index('IsoCode'))
    
    # Reset the DataFrame index
    usedCurrencies.reset_index(inplace=True)
    
    # Format the data into a python dict, this allows us to update to salesforce
    dataToSalesforce = usedCurrencies[['Id','ConversionRate']].to_dict(orient='records')
    
    # Update the data to salesforce
    uploadToSalesforce(sf, dataToSalesforce)
```

Sample of the rows in excel

[image]

what it looks like now after i assign headers
[image]

the columns i actually want

[image]

what the end result will be prior to turning into a python dict and being sent to salesforce

[image]

sample in txt

```
"ANG  Curncy",0,3,"Neth. Ant. Guilder Spot",1.790000  ,"N",
"ALLEUR  Curncy",0,3,"ALL-EUR Cross Rate(x100)",.901100  , ,
```

the data before any modification

[image]

txt version of that same data:

```
START-OF-FIELDS
NAME
PRIOR_CLOSE_MID
INVERSE_QUOTED
END-OF-FIELDS

TIMESTARTED=Tue Apr 25 21:15:12 EDT 2023
START-OF-DATA
"ALL  Curncy",0,3,"Albanian Lek Spot",101.180000  ,"N",
"ANG  Curncy",0,3,"Neth. Ant. Guilder Spot",1.790000  ,"N",
"ARS  Curncy",0,3,"Argentine Peso Spot",220.883000  ,"N",
"AUD  Curncy",0,3,"Australian Dollar Spot",.662600  ,"Y",
"BBD  Curncy",0,3,"Barbados Dollar Spot",2.000000  ,"N",
END-OF-DATA
TIMEFINISHED=Tue Apr 25 21:15:21 EDT 2023
END-OF-FILE
```

Comment: If you load in the data, then create the "cols" list you can ensure you have the correct columns. Can we get a screenshot of what you would want it to look like?

Comment: added screenshots at the bottom of the post

Comment: Why do you need to remove them in the dataframe? Couldn't you just remove them in the dict? `filter(lambda x: x in ["IsoCode", "ConversionRate"], dataToSalesforce)`. Edit: you would have to convert it back to a dict before sending it

Comment: Say i didn't need to remove them doesn't matter because the problem remains how do i assign headers dynamically based on the content with each column. Also i need to remove them anyways because when i've tried not removing them and updating the salesforce data via usedCurrencies.update() it has an error because the dataframe being updated being the data from salesforce, doesn't contain those other columns that are in the csv.

Comment: if you know way to use dataFrame.update() to only update a specific column (this case using primary key of 'IsoCode' to update 'ConversionRate' I'll drop the piece of code where i'm dropping the other columns